# Does 'synchronized' influence stream's memory footprint?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, out-of-memory

We have a weird case of OutOfMemory (heap). Given this method

```
private void processRemainingIds(final ITransaction tx) {
    remainingIds.stream()//
        .map(this::getInternalMessage)//
        .filter(this::isMessageNeedsProcessing)//
        .forEach(msg -> registerMessageAsMissing(msg, tx));
}
```

if remainingIds is sufficiently large, this method fills up the heap quite steadily.

- `getInternalMessage` will load a data model structure of "normal" size (ie. no blobs / clobs etc, just a few dozen strings and numbers)
- `registerMessageAsMissing` internally calls a synchronized method (maybe that's relevant)
- **making `getInternalMessage` 'synchronized' changes the memory behavior entirely, the heap size doesn't increase anymore**

I'd expect the above implementation to create a lot of internal messages, check and if needed process them, but then discard each object and occasionally run GC. But that's not what we're seeing, instead we get

[image: Growing heap]

The standard issues of OOM, ie. "something is holding on to your objects" I'm familiar with. But why does making `getInternalMessage` synchronized change anything?

Comment: If it's `synchronized` then I'd expect it to use less memory since only one thread at a time is using the heap space needed by that `synchronized` method. However, I think this stream processes its elements serially, so it's odd that synchronized would make any difference in that regard..

Comment: @xtratic, remainingIds is a Set, see we have an unordered, sequential stream. And so my point exactly, I don't see the concurrency and thus why 'synchronized' would matter.

Comment: Is there any way we could see all the code relevant to this? With some redacted if needed.

Comment: what GC, what are the VM arguments you started it with?

Comment: Thanks @xtratic and Eugene for your feedback. The issue is becoming clearer. The root cause is an EclipseLink UnitOfWork holding references to all objects loaded in getInternalMessage(). These are read-only, and the assumption was they'd get GC'd. Using a "FORCE_WEAK" reference mode solves the problem.
We did see a different memory graph when making "getInternalMessage" synchronized, but I'm attributing that to possibly more GC cycles or some fluke.

Comment: What is the correlation between `UnitOfWork` and `synchronized`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, honsetly, I think there is none. By now I'm pretty sure the "synchronized" was a red herring. It did have an effect on the memory graph, but I'm putting that down to some erratic GC and/or caching behavior. I'm not sure how to document the issue here, as there isn't really an answer (except "No, it doesn't")

Comment: @Simon I'd suggest that you write a short answer to the question explaining what was the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out changing to "synchronized" was a red herring, it was neither the cause nor solution.

The cause was EclipseLink's UnitOfWork, which by default holds a reference to each loaded entity. As `getInternalMessage()` was loading many objects, the heap slowly filled up. The solution was to use `ReferenceMode.FORCE_WEAK`, which only creates weak references to loaded entities, and thus allows for them to be GC'ed.

I'd speculate that making `getInternalMessage()` **synchronized** changed the execution such that objects were loaded slower, maybe giving GC a bit more time. This might've resulted in a slower memory incline over the same period of time, but we later found that with synchronized too we ran into an OOM.